# What is the difference between $dr$ and $d^{3}x$ when we integrate a 3 dimensional function?

Tags: integration

When I am integrating a 3 dimensional function, e.g. doing Fourier transformation for $f(\vec r)$ whose domain of definition is $\mathbf{R}^3$ with $\vec r = (x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})$, I found two types of formulas: $\hat{f}(\vec k) = \int d\vec r f(\vec r)exp(-i\vec k \cdot \vec r)$ and $\hat{f}(\vec k) = \int d^{3}x f(\vec r)exp(-i\vec k \cdot \vec r)$.

Therefore, is this equation right?$$d\vec r = d^{3}x = dx_{1}dx_{2}dx_{3}$$which stands for the infinitesimal volume in $\mathbf{R}^3$? However, if the equation,  $\hat{f}(\vec k) = \int d\vec r f(\vec r)exp(-i\vec k \cdot \vec r)$, is right, should $\hat{f}(\vec k)$ be a vector?

Also, what is its meaning when $d\hat{n}$, where $\hat{n}$ is a unit length vector in $\mathbf R ^3$, appears in an integration? Does it mean an integration over a unit sphere?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you give more context to your $d\hat n$ question?

Comment: Yes, $d\hat{n}$ probably is the [solid angle measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) and is used in integration over a sphere.

Comment: I don't like any of the notations proposed here. Nowadays the $d\vec r$ is mostly used in line integrals $\int_\gamma\vec F\cdot d\vec r$; the $d^3$ refers to triple differentiation, etc. The shown notations are caused by a pre-war (non-) understanding of multivariate calculus. The $\to$s cause a headache anyway.

Comment: @Kusma For example, if the $\vec r$ here inside the expression of $f(\vec r)$ has a fixed length of $r_0$, i.e. $\vec r = r_0 \hat n$ where $\hat n$ is the unit vector, the integration here could be expressed using another form with respect to $d\hat n$ over the unit sphere, according to what I encountered in some literature. (Sorry that I don not know how to correctly convert the Fourier transformation here into the integration form with respect to $d\hat n$, since what I have seen is a much more complex context in polymer physics.)

Answer (score 1):

Notation isn't uniform in mathematics (and even less in its applications), so check your sources for the definitions they use. Your equation $d\vec{r}=d^3x=dx_1dx_2dx_3$ indeed expresses the same thing in different notations. Despite the vector arrow, I expect $d\vec{r}$ to not mean a vectorial quantity, but that integration is with respect to 3D Lebesgue measure (or in more intuitive terms, representing the infinitesimal volume element).

$\hat f (\vec k)$ should not be a vector (unless $f(\vec r)$ is a vector).